# Trying to tokenise Ethereum TX sender "from" to crosscheck values

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum, web3py

Trying to get back to python with a web3 project. I am trying to extrapolate precise values from a tx (from, to, value) to crosscheck via python if those values are the expected one.

```
txtest = web3.eth.get_transaction('0x877af182f545cde910544f2f869429fc7bd66f24fb58b42b1f691667f26c95c4')
finaltx = txtest.to
print('This is the raw tx result ', txtest)
print('This is the sender address: ', finaltx)
```

perfectly works:

```
This is the raw tx result  AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x3ec30c2f44d15e55e3caee66ae238819ae2809d81a0df6b0ca58fa722a78ae91'), 'blockNumber': 16751195, 'from': '0xDAFEA492D9c6733ae3d56b7Ed1ADB60692c98Bc5', 'gas': 21000, 'gasPrice': 22256602635, 'maxFeePerGas': 22256602635, 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 0, 'hash': HexBytes('0x877af182f545cde910544f2f869429fc7bd66f24fb58b42b1f691667f26c95c4'), 'input': '0x', 'nonce': 252468, 'to': '0xe688b84b23f322a994A53dbF8E15FA82CDB71127', 'transactionIndex': 166, 'value': 274458557610409937, 'type': '0x2', 'accessList': [], 'chainId': '0x1', 'v': 0, 'r': HexBytes('0xe2a1cf9bf7ec838468a03929c535a536462e6e4cde2978e4a1e39826a738f534'), 's': HexBytes('0x08a9073666cb98adcd7166ffc216f1b23b09b9463a703440427047cae6d95217')})
This is the sender address:  0xe688b84b23f322a994A53dbF8E15FA82CDB71127
```

but if i try to fetch the "from" in the AttributeDict with `finaltx = txtest.from` then i can't run the code:

```
txtest = web3.eth.get_transaction('0x877af182f545cde910544f2f869429fc7bd66f24fb58b42b1f691667f26c95c4')
finaltx = txtest.to
print('This is the raw tx result ', txtest)
print('This is the sender address: ', finaltx)
addressfrom = txtest.from
```

errors with

```
finaltx = txtest.from
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say "I can't run the code", what does that mean? Do you get a certain error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Also, the code you posted doesn't define what `web3.eth.get_transaction` returns. I _infer_ from the rest of the question that it returns an `AttributeDict` like the one you've shown — is that correct?

Comment: @DanJ when i say the code doesn't run, i mean `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
sh-3.2# python3 testbot.py 
  File "testbot.py", line 20
    finaltx = txtest.from
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I don't need to return the AttributeDict because i get that completely and i return the only 3 tokenised items i need.

Problem is idk how to turn finaltx = txtest.from into a variable without having it throwing syntax errors

Comment: Updated the issue with code working code and not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Might sound dumb from me but as `from` is reserved for code, in order to call `addressfrom = txtest.from` in a readable state for python, it has to be passed with `getattr()`, so the solution is:

```
addressfrom = getattr(txtest, 'from')
print(addressfrom)
```

which outputs the right address ^^